# Commit after MessageBox in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this code in my winform C# application:

```
public void InsertValidationDate(Validar v, string descanso)
        {
            bool insert = false;

            try
            {
                bd.con.Open();
                bdag.bd.trans = bdag.bd.con.BeginTransaction();

                insert = InsertDate(v);

                if (insert == true)
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("Insert Ok");

                   pk = ReturnInsertDate(DateTime.Parse(v.Date), v.User);
                   insert = UpdateReference(DateTime.Parse(v.Date), pk);

                   if (insert == false)
                    {
                        Rollback();
                        MessageBox.Show("Update Error");                         
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Commit();
                        MessageBox.Show("Update OK");   
                    }   
               }                   

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Rollback();

            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

After displaying the message ("Insert Ok") the connection to the database is closed and the transaction is not posible commited. Why? Because the Insert function don't close the database connection. Any Ideas? Thanks!!.

```
        public int ReturnInsertDate(DateTime date, int user)
        {
            int validate = -1;

            try
            {
                bd.CadSQL = "select " + bd.Validar.id + " from " + bd.Validar.tabla + " where ";
                bd.CadSQL += bd.Validar.date + " = '" + date.Year + "-" + date.Month.ToString("d2") + "-" + date.Day.ToString("d2") + "'";
                bd.CadSQL += " and " + bd.Validar.user+ " = " + user;

                bd.comandoSQL.CommandText = bd.CadSQL;
                bd.reader = bd.comandoSQL.ExecuteReader();

                while (bd.reader.Read())
                {
                    if (!bd.reader.IsDBNull(0))
                        validate = bd.reader.GetInt32(0);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                bd.reader.Close();
            }

            return validate;
        }

        public bool UpdateReference(DateTime date, int validate)
        {
            bool updateR = false;

            try
            {
                bd.CadSQL = "update " + bd.Fichar.tabla;
                bd.CadSQL += " set " + bd.Fichar.validateId + " = " + validate;
                bd.CadSQL += " where " + bd.Fichar.date + " = '" + date.Year + "-" + date.Month.ToString("d2") + "-" + date.Day.ToString("d2") + "'";

                bd.comandoSQL.CommandText = bd.CadSQL;
                bd.comandoSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();

                updateR = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            return updateR ;
        }
```

Comment: what is  Insert(v).....

Comment: Insert is a function to insert into database the hours that I am working in my job in a table validation, after I update this id validation into other table. Thanks

Comment: Did you close the connection in the InsertDate, ReturnInsertDate or UpdateReference ?

Comment: Does InsertDate(v) actually use the same transaction object?

Comment: Yes. I am using the same transaction object

Comment: Show the code for `ReturnInsertDate` and `UpdateReference` otherwise how can we tell why this is happening?

Comment: ReturnInsertDate(DateTime.Parse(v.Date), v.User, false); doesn't point towards public int ReturnInsertDate(DateTime date, int user); you send 3 parameters and your function only expects 2; Also bd.con != con

Comment: Steve. I don't close the database connection into InsertDate, ReturnInsertDate or UpdateReference

Comment: What are these Commit and Rollback methods? Do they work with the object on which the transaction has been started i.e. `bdag.bd.trans`. What happen if, instead of using these methods you call directly `bdag.bd.trans.Commit();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would set your transaction as follows since it seems you are working with different connection objects.

```
using (var scope = TransactionHelper.Instance)
{
 var process = true;
 var aMessage = "";
 try
 {
   //Enter you code and functions here
   //Whenever you find a piece of code to be working incorrectly, Raise an error
   if(!someCode(blabla))
      throw new Exception("This someCode quited on me!");
   //Whenever your code does what it needs to do, end with a commit
   scope.Commit();
 }
 catch(Exception ex) //Catch whatever exception might occur
 {
  scope.FullRollBack(); 
  aMessage = ex.Message;
  process = false;
 }
 finally 
 {
  //only here you will use messageboxes to explain what did occur during the process
  if (process)
    MessageBox.Show("Succesfully Committed!");
  else
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Rollback occurred, exception Message: {0}"
                    , aMessage);
 }
}
```

Comment: What is the using reference to TransactionHelper?

Comment: a using reference is kinda helpfull while working with IDisposable objects like connections (you don't want the connection to be open all the time; the transactionhelper simply stands above all the other connections and on the end of it will Commit or Rollback all operations that might/should have occurred. We use this scenario for testing

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit strange that you're referring to `con` when you open the connection, and then you use `bdag.bd.con` for the `BeginTransaction` call.  Are you absolutely certain these two variables are pointing to the same connection object?

Comment: Probably you are on the right track. Also the Commit() and Rollback() as standalone methods hint that something is working with different objects

Comment: Yes, It was a mistake when I wrote the code. Sorry.